# Email is not sending in Ruby on Rails Forgot Password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

Hi My forgot password is not sending email.
This is the code. All the other emails are going fine.

Please guide.

```
class Devise::PasswordsController < DeviseController
 prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication
 # Render the #edit only if coming from a reset password email link
 append_before_filter :assert_reset_token_passed, :only => :edit

 # GET /resource/password/new
 def new
build_resource({})
resource.send_instructions_to = 'email'
 end

 # POST /resource/password
 def create
if params[:user]['send_instructions_to'] == 'email'
  self.resource =       resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(resource_params)
  self.resource.send_instructions_to = 'email'
  if successfully_sent?(resource)
    respond_with({}, :location => after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
  else
    respond_with(resource)
      end
elsif params[:user]['send_instructions_to'] == 'phone'
  self.resource = resource_class.send_new_password_to_phone(resource_params)
  if resource === true 
    flash[:notice] = 'We changed the password and sent it to your mobile phone'
    respond_with({},
                 location: after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = 'There is no such number'
    render :new
  end
end
  end

  # GET /resource/password/edit?reset_password_token=abcdef
  def edit
self.resource = resource_class.new
resource.reset_password_token = params[:reset_password_token]
  end

  # PUT /resource/password
  def update
self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(resource_params)

if resource.errors.empty?
  flash_message = resource.active_for_authentication? ? :updated : :updated_not_active
  set_flash_message(:notice, flash_message) if is_navigational_format?
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
else
  respond_with resource
end
  end

  protected

  # The path used after sending reset password instructions
  def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
    new_session_path(resource_name)
  end

  # Check if a reset_password_token is provided in the request
  def assert_reset_token_passed
if params[:reset_password_token].blank?
  set_flash_message(:error, :no_token)
  redirect_to new_session_path(resource_name)
    end
  end
end
```

I have tried a couple of things but these dont work. Which files or settings should i check to correct this.

The server logs says 302

```
Started POST "/users/password" for 106.51.138.36 at 2016-09-20 06:39:43   +0000
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   "authenticity_token"=>"euWMVUjYgc++Wc9QQXqjOGvryuYYt2G62MwmEEnT15g=", "user"=>   {"send_instructions_to"=>"email", "mobile_phone_attributes"=>{"number"=>""}, "email"=>"nitefoodie@gmail.com"}, "commit"=>"Send instructions"}
============================User(id: integer, email: string,    encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string,    reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count:    integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime,    current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, confirmation_token: string,   confirmed_at: datetime, confirmation_sent_at: datetime, type: string, slug: string, name: string, surname: string, individual: boolean, company_name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, zip_code_id: integer, invitation_id: integer, description: text, image: string, address: string,   special_offers: text, guest: boolean)====
======================RESOURCE============#      <Contractor:0x00000008420308>=============================
=====================COMING IN IF=========================
Redirected to http://www.estimatemyproject.com/users/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: I get a 302 Added in the post

Comment: This sound be a good use for a debugger so you can place a breakpoint and see if the right code is being run